# Laravel 5 and Length Aware Pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've got another pagination problem it looks like. When I iterate over the paginated array below, I get the entire array every page.

```
$array = [...];
$ret = new LengthAwarePaginator($array, count($array), 10);
// dd($ret);

LengthAwarePaginator {#302 ▼
  #total: 97
  #lastPage: 10
  #items: Collection {#201 ▼
    #items: array:97 [▶]
  }
  #perPage: 10
  #currentPage: 1
  #path: "/"
  #query: []
  #fragment: null
  #pageName: "page"
}
```

This isn't the case when building a LAP from an eloquent model eg: `Blah::paginate()`

Answer (score 19):

The paginator does not slice the given array for you automatically. You have to slice it yourself before you pass it to the paginator.

To make life easier for you, use the `collect` helper to create an instance of a laravel collection, which makes it very easy to slice up:

```php
$items = collect([...]);
$page = Input::get('page', 1);
$perPage = 10;

$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator(
    $items->forPage($page, $perPage), $items->count(), $perPage, $page
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The LengthAwarePaginator does not chunk autmoatically.

An quick fix is to do something similar:

```
foreach($col->slice($col->perPage() * ($col->currentPage() - 1), $col->perPage()) as $item)
{
     // do blah
}
```